# Direct3D Full Screen( CreateDevice return D3DERR_INVALIDCALL )

Tags: directx, fullscreen, direct3d

I want to Direct3D full screen using MFC.

I made a Custom Static Class. this class initialize direct3d.

I success to window mode. but Full screen mode is failed.

CreateDevice function return D3DERR_INVALIDCALL(-2005530516).

How to Solve it??

Initial

```
// Create the D3D object.
if( NULL == ( m_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION ) ) )
    return E_FAIL;

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof( d3dpp ) );
d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 1920;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 1080;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = m_hWnd;

HRESULT temp;
// Create the D3DDevice
if( FAILED( temp = m_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd,
                                  D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                  &d3dpp, &m_pd3dDevice ) ) )
{
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Turn on the zbuffer
m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE );

m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_AMBIENT, 0xffffffff );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass m_hWnd to CreateDevice instead of AfxGetMainWindow. 
Or d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = AfxGetMainWindow. 
Maybe your m_hWnd is invalid.

Comment: I try to AfxGetMainWindow instead of m_hwnd. but still same symptom. I guess Dialog Handle can't access Direct3D Full Screen Mode. Is it right??

Comment: Full-screen has a number of special requirements, so likely the MFC-based window isn't set up with the proper style. That said, why in the world would you want to be full screen exclusive and use MFC? None of the MFC controls are visible on a Direct3D surface, so why use it in the first place? Windowed mode is the only sensible thing to do. Of course, I'd also probably question the need to use legacy Direct3D 9 instead of Direct3D 11.

Comment: because I want to use Direct3D in Dialog Based Project. So Make Toggle Button and that swap mode(full <-> windowed). I try to Use Direct3D 11. Thanks for reply.

Comment: In this case you maybe should create a separate window for fullscreen mode. Although I don't see a reason why the dialog hwnd cannot be used too. Maybe it's not the problem. Maybe you can try different BackBufferFormat or without a depthstencil too. Or lower width height.